# Unable to get proper data in Excel when getting from REST via AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, spring-restcontroller

Trying to get excel sheet with data using OutputStream but not able to get data and only getting bytes when trying to use angularjs FileSaver.

```
         var blob = new Blob([result.data],  {type : 'application/vnd.ms-excel'});
         FileSaver.saveAs(blob, "Report.xls");
```

Route call

```
 var promise = $http.get(urlLink + '/downloadxls', {
            params: {
                search_param: searchParam
            }
        },{cache: true,responseType: 'arraybuffer',headers: {
   'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream; charset=x-user-defined'
}});
```

Response Header

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:x-requested-with, content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Access-Control-Max-Age:3600
Content-Type:application/vnd.ms-excel;charset=UTF-8
Date:Mon, 26 Sep 2016 06:02:33 GMT
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Application-Context:application:8080
```

Request Headers

```
Provisional headers are shown
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Origin:http://localhost:9000
Referer:http://localhost:9000/
```

In Spring REST service ,

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition",
            "attachment; filename=MyExcel.xls");
response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
```

Getting Bytes in Excelsheet not as data in proper alignment but in backend can able to save the data properly,

ï¿½ï¿½à¡±ï¿½;ï¿½ï¿½   'ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½(ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½   ï¿½ï¿½Aï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½\pvijayas                                                                                                      Bï¿½a=ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½=h:ï¿½#8X@ï¿½"ï¿½ï¿½1ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Arial1ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Arial1ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Arial1ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Arial1ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Arial"$"#,##0_);("$"#,##0)"$"#,##0_);Red "$"#,##0.00_);("$"#,##0.00)% "$"#,##0.00_);Red,*'_(* #,##0_);*(* (#,##0);*(* "-"*);*(@*)5)0*("$"* #,##0_);*("$"* (#,##0);*("$"* "-"*);*(@*)=,8*("$"* #,##0.00_);*("$"* (#,##0.00);*("$"* "-"??*);*(@*)4+/*(* #,##0.00_);*(* (#,##0.00);*(* "-"??*);*(@_)ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ ï¿½ ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ ï¿½ï¿½ ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ ï¿½ï¿½ ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ ï¿½ï¿½ ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ ï¿½ï¿½ ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ ï¿½ï¿½ ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ ï¿½ï¿½ ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ ï¿½ï¿½ ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ ï¿½ï¿½ ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ ï¿½ï¿½ ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ ï¿½ï¿½ ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ ï¿½ï¿½ ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ ï¿½ï¿½ ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ ï¿½ï¿½ ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ ï¿½ï¿½ ï¿½ ï¿½ ï¿½+ï¿½ï¿½ ï¿½ï¿½ ï¿½)ï¿½ï¿½ ï¿½ï¿½ ï¿½,ï¿½ï¿½ ï¿½ï¿½ ï¿½*ï¿½ï¿½ ï¿½ï¿½ ï¿½   ï¿½ï¿½ ï¿½ï¿½ ï¿½  ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½`ï¿½OPeople listï¿½ï¿½ï¿½#ï¿½ï¿½ID